# Will QFile::copy create create a copy of the file or move the contents from one file to another?

Tags: c++, qfile

I am trying to copy a file from one location to another( in a device) using C++/Qt

I tried QFile::copy("path1/file","path2");

I want to copy the file in path1 to path2. path2 does not have the file.

I just want to know if this is the right way because the above code does not seem to work.

Also, should I do a file open before I try to copy? Need help!

Comment: Also, have you verified in the docs that your plan for using this function is supported? http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qfile.html#copy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to copy `path1/file` into `path2` with the same file name, you'll want to do:

```
QFile::copy("path1/file", "path2/file");
```

Copy allows you to change the name of the file. Example:

```
QFile::copy("path1/file1", "path1/file2");
```

Which is why you need to include the file name both times. Also, it is not necessary to open the file first. And to answer the title question, it copies the file. `QFile::rename()` moves the contents.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. This Qfile copy would return false in case file already exists in the destination location. I want to copy the file first time and every time the contents of source file is modified. In the second case I have to go for QFile rename()?

Comment: No. Both copy and rename will fail if the file already exists. You have to delete the destination file first.

Comment: Can this be used to copy a **resource file** to some path? For example, is `QFile::copy(":/default.jpg", "data.jpg");` possible?

Comment: @ThePeacefulCoder You should ask that as a new question. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: @ThePeacefulCoder This link claims that it does work for copying a resource file: https://forum.qt.io/topic/13131/how-to-extract-a-resource-from-qrc-solved/2